# Is there a testNG reports repository

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testng

Where can i save my testNG reports for analysis later.
My regression suite will be running daily and I want to store the reports for anaysis and comparitive study later.
What can i use for the same?

Answer (score 2):

[Allure](http://allure.qatools.ru/), [ReportPortal](http://reportportal.io/#documentation/Test-framework-integration%3Etestng) or maybe some other tools could help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such repository. You can go ahead and build a customized `org.testng.IReporter` which persists the test results to a database which you can fetch and run your analysis.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you can go database..

Generally i used custom HTML reports for suite and links to Tests HTML reports. I will create dir with data and time stamp for every run and move to shared location to keep and share.